# Swiftで配列にUIImage!を代入→nilだから代入できない？

Tags: swift, uiimage

```
var gazoui:[UIImage]!
var gazouiii:UIImage
gazouiii = UIImage(named: "m1.gif")!
gazoui[1] = UIImage(named: "m1.gif")!
```

m1.gifはプロジェクトに入ってます
エンコードはできるんですがすぐにシミュレーターが落ちます
`gazouiii` のほうの代入はできていて `gazouiii` は `nil` ではなくなるんですが`gazoui[1]` のほうで "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" のエラーで落ちます
なぜですか？

for文で配列に一気に連番の画像をUIImageで入れるのが目的です

Answer (score 0, accepted):

オブジェクトの宣言とイニシアライズの基礎について、まず説明します。
非Optional型と、Optional型では、イニシアライズのしかたが異なります。

```
var images: [UIImage]?
// var images: [UIImage]! でもおなじ
println(images == nil)
```

出力は`true`になります。Optional型を宣言すると、初期値がに`nil`になります。対して非Optional型は、宣言しても変数には`nil`は入らず、「処理が完結していない」状態になります。

```
var images: [UIImage] // このままでは未完のコード
images = [UIImage]()
```

---

```
import UIKit

var images: [UIImage] = [UIImage]() // (1)
let image1 = UIImage(named: "picture1.png")
images.append(image1) // (2)
let image2 = UIImage(named: "picture2.png")
images.append(image2)
```

非Optional型なら、オブジェクトが`nil`でないことが保証されますので、`nil`のオブジェクトを操作することで起きるエラーを、心配しなくてよくなります。(1)
配列に要素を追加するには、メソッド`append()`を使うと便利。(2)

> エンコードはできるんですがすぐにシミュレーターが落ちます

「エンコード」じゃなくて**ビルド**といいますね。

Comment: 配列の初期化について 勉強になりました。こちらの書き方ならOptional型を使わずにいけるぶん安心ですね。
回答ありがとうございました！
エンコードはおかしいですね笑

Answer (score 1):

gazouiがnilになってるのが原因ではないでしょうか？
これが配列を参照するようにすれば、正常に動作すると思われます。

```
var gazoui:[UIImage]! = Array<UIImage>(count: 2, repeatedValue: UIImage())
var gazouiii:UIImage
gazouiii = UIImage(named: "m1.gif")!
gazoui[1] = UIImage(named: "m1.gif")!
```

Comment: Array<UIImage>(count: 2, repeatedValue: UIImage())
こういう配列の要素数を指定する書き方があったんですね。勉強不足でした。
解決できました！ありがとうございます。